# How do I convert regex to grep format

Tags: regex, grep

I'm trying to make what I'm able to match in Notepad++ using Regular Expression, have the ability to be grepped. I want to match `email:32characters(a-f0-9):3characters(ANYCHARACTER/SYMBOL)`

Here's an example:

```
Stack@overflow.com:999999999999999999999999999999a1:&U,
```

So far I've been able to match using regex using:

```
[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,6}:[a-f0-9]{32}:
```

But i'm unsure on how to match the last 3 characters (WHICH CAN BE ANYTHING).

Furthermore, when trying to:

```
grep "[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,6}:[a-f0-9]{32}:" input.txt > output.txt
```

Nothing is being outputted to my file which seems strange to me. I am using Cygwin Terminal on Windows to perform these greps.

Comment: Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Accept (i.e. click the "tick" next to it) one of the existing answer, if there are any. You can also create your own answer, and even accept it, if your solution is not yet covered by an existing answer. Compare https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `grep -E` or `egrep` if that is available in your environment.

```
     -E, --extended-regexp
         Interpret pattern as an extended regular expression (i.e. force grep to behave as egrep).
```